# How to get rid of scale factor from CORDIC

Tags: math, vhdl, fpga, register-transfer-level, cordic

From CORDIC, `K_i = cos(tan^-1(2^i))`. As I know the K is approached `0.607xxx`. How do I approach to `0.607xxx`?

Also does it mean that I can use `0.607xxx` instead of `cos(tan^-1(2^I))`? I am citing from [this article](http://www.ijera.com/papers/Vol3_issue2/DK32696699.pdf).

I am trying to implement hyperbolic tanh function. And so far I understand (6) equation. I'm not sure about how to make the K and how to use it?

## Update :

I want to know where the total scaling concept apply in progress to get sine, cos angle.
Here some example, I set that the specified angle is 20.
And I want to know sine, cos angle. The the process as follows.

> n     d           x            y           angle           K    arctan value
>
> 0    1    0.7071   0.7071   0.7854    0.7071     0.785398
>
> ....
>
> 10  -1   0.9395   0.3426   0.3497        1           0.000976

We can get if specified angle is `20 degree(0.3491)`
Then we get `sine (20) = 0.9395 
Cos(20) = 0.3497`

Done.

But I have still curious about where is the total scaling `concept(0.607)` apply?  Where total scaling `concept(0.607 )` used in progress to get sin, cos angle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each step in the CORDIC algorithm add a scaling of `cos(arctan(2^-i))` (or `1/sqrt(1+2^-2i)`), so for a 4 steps CORDIC, the total scaling is:

```
cos(arctan(2^-0))*cos(arctan(2^-1))*cos(arctan(2^-2))*cos(arctan(2^-3)) = 0.60883
```

If you add more iterations, it gets to 0.607252935 and some. As to what to do with that factor, it's up to you and the function you implement. You may want to remove it and give unscaled result, or your consumer may be able to deal it it more easily.

In the case of `tanh`, I think there is a division of two values with the same scaling, so it would cancel out in that case. I'm really not that sure on that one, since I didn't use CORDIC in this mode, so you will have to figure that out by yourself.

### Update

The advantage of CORDIC is that each iteration is a shift+add on `X` and `Y`. In your example your incorporated the scale factor, which gives the right answer, but isn't necessary and disallow the simple shift + add operation. Thus, we leave the scaling as a post-operation (or initialization), or out entirely if the subsequent module can deal with a scaled answer.

The way to get sin/cos of 20 is, starting with `X = 1; Y = 0; Z = 20`:

```
Z0 = 20 - 45.00 = -25.00; X0 = 1 - 0 = 1; Y0 = 0 + 2^-0 = 1
Z1 = Z0 + 26.57 =   1.57; X1 = X0 + Y0*2^-1 = 1.5000; Y1 = Y0 - X0*2^-1 = 0.5000
Z2 = Z1 - 14.04 = -12.47; X2 = X1 - Y1*2^-2 = 1.3750; Y2 = Y1 + X1*2^-2 = 0.8750
Z3 = Z2 +  7.13 = - 5.35; X3 = X2 + Y2*2^-3 = 1.4844; Y3 = Y2 - X2*2^-3 = 0.7031
Z4 = Z3 +  3.58 = - 1.77; X4 = X3 + Y3*2^-4 = 1.5283; Y4 = Y3 - X3*2^-4 = 0.6104
Z5 = Z4 +  1.79 =   0.02; X5 = X4 + Y4*2^-5 = 1.5474; Y5 = Y4 - X4*2^-5 = 0.5626
Z6 = Z5 -  0.90 = - 0.88; X6 = X5 - Y5*2^-6 = 1.5386; Y6 = Y5 + X5*2^-6 = 0.5868
```

The final answer is scaled: `cos(20) = X6*0.607 = 0.9339` and `sin(20) = Y6*0.607 = 0.3562`. The advantage of ignoring the scaling factor should be obvious, each iteration is `Xi = Xi-1 +- Yi-1 * 2^-i`, which is a shift and add. You also don't need to store the scaling factor in a ROM or somewhere else; the only memory you need is for the arctan(2^-i).

Note that you can get an unscaled result by starting with `X = 0.607` instead of `X = 1`.

Comment: If I have 10 iteration, then can the scale go to 1 from 0.607252935? From Kevin Thibedeau

Comment: The total scaling factor is the multiplication of all the iteration's scaling factors. The scaling of the tenth iteration is approximately 1, which is good since it means the multiplication of all scaling will converge. It converges to 0.607252935

Comment: This is a quit a bit off subject. Why we need the total scaling? I fully understand what if I have iteration then I can get a 0.607.. but why we do get a total scaling value? For what?

Comment: I may have mistake your question, I though you wanted to know where the 0.607 factor comes from. It's the cummulative scaling that comes from the CORDIC algorithm. You need it to "correct" the result of the CORDIC. If you perform polar to rectangular coordinate using CORDIC for example, the length of the vector you get is 1.65 times larger than the expected value. 1.65 is 1/0.607. When the interpretation of result requires "real" result, you must compense for this scaling.

Comment: As I know in the rotation mode, the K is getting from (1/sqrt(1+2^(-2*n)). So when n is going to infinity, K is like this 0.7071 0.8944 0.9701 0.9923 0.9981 0.995 0.9999 1.0000 1.0000 .... but I can't understand the concept about total scaling. Is the total scaling concept  needed in CORDIC polar mode? If you can would you please let me know example ? When total scale is used

Comment: That the scaling the n'th iteration applies. To get more precision on CORDIC, you use more iteration. Since each iteration applies a scaling of 1/sqrt(1+2^-2n), the total scaling after X iteration, if X is large enough, is approximately 0.607 (1/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(1+2^-2)*sqrt(1+2^-4)*sqrt(1+2^-6)...)

Comment: Wow! it is genious! ; How can I determine +,- of Y from  Xi = Xi-1 +- Yi-1 * 2^-i     ,also 
Why do you get Z values? It is used nowhere .

Comment: You initialize Z to the angle you want sin/cos from. You update it with Zi = Zi-1 +- arctan(2^-i). You need Z since it's sign determines the sign of Z, X and Y update.

Answer (score 1):

When using CORDIC you calculate tan and tanh by taking the ratio of sin to cos or sinh to cosh. Since both terms have the scale factor applied to them the K's cancel out and you don't have to do any correction. You do need to be aware of potential issues with overflow and ensure that enough bits are present in the X and Y registers to hold the scaled values. Another option is to prescale the X and Y input values (multiply by 0.607) so that the gain is 1 after running the algorighm.

Comment: Thanks , would you please let me know what is this mean? "Since both terms have the scale factor applied to them the K's cancel out and you don't have to do any correction. " I can't understand it

Comment: @user5014962. hyperbolic CORDIC(a) produces K*cosh(a) and K*sinh(a) as results in the X and Y registers. `(K*sinh(a)) / (K*cosh(a)) = tanh(a)`. The K's cancel in the division without any need to correct for the gain. Note that the scale factor for hyperbolic CORDIC is: `K[i] = sqrt(1-2^(-2i))` which converges to 1 after about 10 iterations instead of 1.647 for the circular implementation.

Comment: Oops. The hyperbolic scale factor converges to 0.82978 without any repeated iterations and 0.82816 with the repeated iterations added (4, 13, 40, ...) to force convergence of the algorithm.